# Scala Customizing Refined Type Exceptions in Http4s

Tags: scala, http4s

I am using [refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) for my requests in order to ensure that the request body confronts to certain specs, such as

```
 case class NewGenreRequest(
      name: GenreNameParam,
      parent: Option[GenreParentParam]
  )
```

where

```
type GenreNameString = String Refined MinSize[3]
```

When the request body sends something with 2 characters, this results in the error `Predicate taking size(me) = 2 failed: Predicate (2 < 3) did not fail.: DownField(name)` in the response body. However I think this isn't the best error to return to the client.

I would like to find a way to customize this response. The logical thing to try was to write a `middleware`

```
 def handleErr(resp: Response[F]): Response[F] =
      resp match {
        case Status.BadRequest(resp) =>
          logger.info("HERE IS MY ERR")
          resp.???? 
        case _ =>
          resp
      }
```

However I need to extract the info regarding which field has failed the predicates. The response body is an fs2 Stream and I am not quite sure about how to go about effectively modifying it using the existing info in the body. I tried `map`ing it but to no result.

Is there an easy way of modifying these error messages?

P.S.: Cross posting from http4s discord as I wasn't able to get an answer

Comment: I would tackle this in the encoder / decoders.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez **cries in boilerplate tears** haha. I was using `derevo` to auto derive the encoders. Given this are a large number of schemas. Writing enc/dec for all of them never the less individually customize them. I assume there isn't something like a middleware for encoders that would allow me to take all encoders and map them through a function without individually modifying them? (enc/dec handled by `circe` )

Comment: You don't need the boilerplate, just use `semiauto` derivation and then use `adaptError`